# This date time literal was not understood

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I get an error saying *"This date time literal was not understood"* with this formula:

```
Private Sub btnOPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOPrint.Click
    If MsgBox("Print Offertory Record?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Print Record") = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        Dim report As New ReportDocument
        report.Load("C:\Users\Paolo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NewMonitoringSystem\NewMonitoringSystem\OffertoryReport.rpt")
        docprint.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
        docprint.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{tblOffertory.Date}=""" & dtpOffertory.Text & """ AND {tblOffertory.Weekly}=#" & txtOffertory.Text & "#"
        docprint.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        docprint.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

If I remove this line...

```
AND {tblOffertory.Weekly}=#" & txtOffertory.Text & "#"
```

...and instead use this line...

```
docprint.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{tblOffertory.Date}=""" & dtpOffertory.Text & """"
```

...it shows the report with no data, just the columns. What formula should I use?

Comment: What are you sending in txtOffertory.Text??

Comment: @Zeina, an amount. I don't really need that line I just put it there to try the code.